# Subconsulta y regresar como cadena

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando que una subconsulta venga como una cadena partida desde una subquery.

Esta es la estructura de la DB (Sé que no es la forma pero cuando llegué así estaba y necesito sacar un trabajo antes de normalizar)

ESTRUCTURA

```
CREATE TABLE `TIENDAS` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `TIENDA` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `EMPLEADOS` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `EMPLEADOS` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `NOMBRE` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

DATOS

```
 EMPLEADOS
    ID | NOMBRE
    1    JUAN PEREZ
    2    PEDRO LOPEZ
    3    MARTIN GUZMAN
    4    OSCAR ACOSTA
    5    ALFONSO HITLER

    TIENDAS
    ID  |  TIENDA  | EMPLEADOS
    1     ACAPULCO   1,2,5
    2     SAN LUIS   4,1
    3     VALLARTA   3
```

Estoy intentando traer los nombres de cada empleado pero no encuentro la forma y esas regresarla como una cadena de nombres

```
$query = "SELECT T.ID, T.TIENDA
(SELECT E.NOMBRE FROM EMPLEADOS E WHERE E.ID IN ( T.EMPLEADOS )) AS EMPLEADOS
FROM TIENDAS T";
```

Espero una salida como esta

```
ID | TIENDA   | EMPLEADOS
1    ACAPULCO   JUAN PEREZ, PEDRO LOPEZ, ALFONSO HITLER
2    SAN LUIS   OSCAR ACOSTA, JUAN PEREZ
3    VALLARTA   MARTIN GUZMAN
```

Pero sinceramente no se como decirle a la DB que la subconsulta la traiga como una cadena delimitada por ","

Gracias

Comment: Si podes, deja el comando CREATE TABLE, para poder replicar tu situación más fácil

Comment: Ya lo agregué, en fin, las tablas reales tienen muchos campos que no tienen nada que ver, pero con ese ejemplo se puede replicar el problema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT T.ID, T.TIENDA, 
(SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(E.NOMBRE) 
 FROM EMPLEADOS E 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(E.ID, T.EMPLEADOS)
 ) AS EMPLEADOS
FROM TIENDAS T;
```

- `GROUP_CONCAT` devuelve una cadena separada por comas a partir de un select
- `FIND_IN_SET` busca la ocurrencia de un campo en una cadena que es una lista separada por comas

---

En caso de que la lista de EMPLEADOS tenga espacios detrás de cada coma (ej: `'1, 2, 5'`) se puede usar un `REPLACE`, algo así:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(E.ID, REPLACE(T.EMPLEADOS, ' ', ''))
```

Comment: Funciona, gracias sensei